# Remove the ')' after parentheses using titlesec

Tags: titlesec

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}

% Set Section Title Formatting %

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[]

\titleformat{\paragraph}{\itshape}{\theparagraph)}{1em}{}[]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at your code, there's a parenthesis after `\theparagraph`. If you remove it, you'll get the desired output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}

% Set Section Title Formatting %

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[]

\titleformat{\paragraph}{\itshape}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that.  Thanks!